# Get best students from each class limit 3 results

Tags: mysql, limit

I need get 2 best students from each class. Try this

```
SELECT t1.nota,t2.sala,t3.serie
FROM aluno AS t1
LEFT JOIN sala AS t2 ON t1.sala = t2.id
LEFT JOIN serie AS t3 ON t1.serie = t3.id

ORDER BY t1.serie,t1.sala,t1.nota

LIMIT t1.nota 2 ??
```

Actual query result in:

```
 
nota    sala    serie
9       1-102   1 ano
8.9     1-102   1 ano
9.1     1-102   1 ano
8.2     1-201   2 ano
9       1-201   2 ano
7.8     1-201   2 ano
9       1-303   3 ano
10      1-303   3 ano
8.7     1-303   3 ano
10      1-102   1 ano
```

I need from

```
 
nota    sala    serie
10      1-102   1 ano
9.1     1-102   1 ano
8.2     1-201   2 ano
9       1-201   2 ano
9       1-303   3 ano
10      1-303   3 ano
```

#### ------

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aluno` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serie` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sala` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nota` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;



INSERT INTO `aluno` (`id`, `serie`, `sala`, `nota`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 9),
(2, 1, 2, 10),
(3, 2, 2, 8),
(4, 2, 2, 9),
(5, 1, 2, 10),
(6, 5, 2, 10),
(7, 3, 3, 8),
(8, 3, 3, 9),
(9, 3, 3, 10),
(10, 3, 3, 10);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sala` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serie` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sala` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;



INSERT INTO `sala` (`id`, `serie`, `sala`) VALUES
(1, '1', '1-101'),
(2, '1', '1-102'),
(3, '1', '1-103'),
(4, '1', '1-104'),
(5, '2', '2-101'),
(6, '2', '2-102'),
(7, '2', '2-103'),
(8, '2', '2-104');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `serie` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serie` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;



INSERT INTO `serie` (`id`, `serie`) VALUES
(1, '1 ano'),
(2, '2 ano');
```

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: Actual query result in:

[code]
nota  sala  serie
9  1-102  1 ano
10  1-102  1 ano
10  1-102  1 ano
8  1-102  2 ano
9  1-102  2 ano
8  1-103  NULL
9  1-103  NULL
10  1-103  NULL
10  1-103  NULL
10  1-102  NULL
[/code]

I need
[code]
nota  sala  serie
10  1-101  1 ano
10  1-101  1 ano
8  1-102  2 ano
9  1-102  2 ano
8  1-103  3 ano
9  1-103  3 ano
10  1-104  1 ano
10  1-104  1 ano[/code]

Comment: Your data set does not correspond to your result set, and that query could not provide *that* result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@strawberry and @sgedds thanks for your attemption. I find a solution with

```
set @num := 0, @salas := '';
select t1.id, t3.serie,t2.sala, t1.nome,t1.nota,t1.sala,
  @num := if(@salas = t1.sala, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
  @cols := t1.sala as dummy
from aluno AS t1
LEFT JOIN sala AS t2 on t1.sala = t2.id
LEFT JOIN serie AS t3 on t1.serie = t3.id
WHERE t2.id IN(10,11,12) AND t1.nota >='8'
having dummy <=11
ORDER BY t3.serie ASC,t2.sala ASC, t1.nota DESC,nome ASC
```